# How to execute a Python3 script from Bash, in the shorthand fashion?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm converting all my Python2 scripts to work with Python3.

From within a bash wrapper, scripts can be executed with Python3 with:

```
python3 myScript.py
```

However, I have an old wrapper which called a Python2 script via the shorthand, i.e

```
./myScript.py
```

How do I ensure that this shorthand will run the script with Python3 by default?

The server these scripts are running on is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "hash-bang" `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: I think you mean "she-bang", and the preferred way to do it would be `#!/usr/bin/env python` since not every distribution will have python in that location (for example NixOS)

Comment: Yeah depends on the unix Flavors  she-bang/hash-bangs.https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/

Answer (score 0):

more information regarding your operating system would be helpful.  If you are on linux or mac you can add the following to the first line of your script:

#!/usr/local/bin/python

adjusting for the location of your python3.  Then you could change the file to executable using:

chmod u+x script

After this you would be able to run your script with just

script

Comment: Added OS info in description

Comment: You can use `#!/usr/bin/env python` to avoid hardcoding the location of the python interpreter.

Comment: @SitiSchu, wouldn't that end up hard coding your python interpreter to what is in /usr/bin/env?

Comment: @Kelvin note the space, it runs `/usr/bin/env` with `python` as argument. `env` will run the first python it finds in your `$PATH`. More info here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429517/7228176

Comment: on my Mac it requires /usr/bin/env python3 for this to work

Comment: @Sitischu, neat! I like it